# Can't launch JavaFX-Maven application from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, javafx

I have a working non-modular JavaFX application managed in Eclipse 2022-03, (with e(fx)clipse 3.8.0 and M2E 1.20.1) for which initially I linked the JavaFX jars in Eclipse using the Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Build Path -> User Libraries. Later on, when the project increased, I switched to Maven but only for the additional jaxb and javacv libraries. The JavaFX embedding was still based on the User Libraries. That worked fine until now. Now that I have a first version 1.0 ready, I wanted to come up with an executable jar to deploy the application on other laptops. The executable jar produced from Eclipse didn't work and I belief that this mixed setup is not useful, also considering to potential use jpackage later on. Hence, I started to clean up my project by deleting JavaFX jars from the Eclipse User Libraries and altered my pom.xml based on the Maven chapter of https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-Eclipse. The versioning for maven and the plugins I took from my old setup and from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3eE-xz-l2mY since the other article seems to date back to 2020.

My pom.xml now looks like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
<artifactId>Sifu</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Sifu</name>
<description>Training planning and execution</description>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.release>15</maven.compiler.release>
    <javafx.version>19</javafx.version>
    <javafx.maven.plugin.version>0.0.8</javafx.maven.plugin.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <!-- JavaFX -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>${javafx.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-media</artifactId>
        <version>${javafx.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-swing</artifactId>
        <version>${javafx.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
        <version>${javafx.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- JAXB API only -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JAXB Implementation -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Framegrabber to get image from movies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
        <artifactId>javacv-platform</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <release>${maven.compiler.release}</release>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.maven.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>application.Main</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Following the openjfx article, I created a run configuration
[image]

When I click run, I get

```
---------------------------------------------------
constituent[0]: file:/C:/Users/alevi/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/
constituent[1]: file:/C:/Users/alevi/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/maven-core-3.8.4.jar
constituent[2]: file:/C:/Users/alevi/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/maven-model-3.8.4.jar
constituent[3]: file:/C:/Users/alevi/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/maven-settings-3.8.4.jar
constituent[4]: file:/C:/Users/alevi/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/maven-settings-builder-3.8.4.jar
constituent[5]: file:/C:/Users/alevi/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/maven-builder-support-3.8.4.jar
constituent[6]: file:/C:/Users/alevi/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/maven-repository-metadata-3.8.4.jar
constituent[7]: file:/C:/Users/alevi/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/maven-artifact-3.8.4.jar
constituent[8]: file:/C:/Users/alevi/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/maven-plugin-api-3.8.4.jar
constituent[9]: file:/C:/Users/alevi/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/maven-model-builder-3.8.4.jar
constituent[10]: file:/C:/Users/alevi/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/maven-resolver-provider-3.8.4.jar
constituent[11]: file:/C:/Users/alevi/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/maven-resolver-api-1.6.3.jar
constituent[12]: file:/C:/Users/alevi/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/maven-resolver-spi-1.6.3.jar
constituent[13]: file:/C:/Users/alevi/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/maven-resolver-util-1.6.3.jar
constituent[14]: file:/C:/Users/alevi/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/maven-shared-utils-3.3.4.jar
constituent[15]: file:/C:/Users/alevi/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/commons-io-2.6.jar
constituent[16]: file:/C:/Users/alevi/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/org.eclipse.sisu.inject-0.3.5.jar
constituent[17]: file:/C:/Users/alevi/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/guice-4.2.2-no_aop.jar
constituent[18]: file:/C:/Users/alevi/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/plexus-utils-3.3.0.jar
constituent[19]: file:/C:/Users/alevi/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/plexus-interpolation-1.26.jar
constituent[20]: file:/C:/Users/alevi/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/plexus-component-annotations-2.1.0.jar
constituent[21]: file:/C:/Users/alevi/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/commons-lang3-3.8.1.jar
constituent[22]: file:/C:/Users/alevi/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/maven-embedder-3.8.4.jar
constituent[23]: file:/C:/Users/alevi/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar
constituent[24]: file:/C:/Users/alevi/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/plexus-sec-dispatcher-2.0.jar
constituent[25]: file:/C:/Users/alevi/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/plexus-cipher-2.0.jar
constituent[26]: file:/C:/Users/alevi/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/commons-cli-1.4.jar
constituent[27]: file:/C:/Users/alevi/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/maven-compat-3.8.4.jar
constituent[28]: file:/C:/Users/alevi/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/wagon-provider-api-3.4.3.jar
constituent[29]: file:/C:/Users/alevi/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/org.eclipse.sisu.plexus-0.3.5.jar
constituent[30]: file:/C:/Users/alevi/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/aether-connector-okhttp-0.17.8.jar
constituent[31]: file:/C:/Users/alevi/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/okhttp-3.14.1.jar
constituent[32]: file:/C:/Users/alevi/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/okio-1.17.3.jar
constituent[33]: file:/C:/Users/alevi/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/maven-resolver-impl-1.6.3.jar
constituent[34]: file:/C:/Users/alevi/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/maven-resolver-connector-basic-1.6.3.jar
constituent[35]: file:/C:/Users/alevi/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/maven-resolver-transport-wagon-1.6.3.jar
constituent[36]: file:/C:/Users/alevi/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/wagon-file-3.4.3.jar
constituent[37]: file:/C:/Users/alevi/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/jansi-2.4.0.jar
constituent[38]: file:/C:/Users/alevi/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime.slf4j.simple_1.18.1.20211008-0657/
constituent[39]: file:/C:/Users/alevi/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime.slf4j.simple_1.18.1.20211008-0657/jars/slf4j-simple-1.7.30.jar
constituent[40]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/Eclipse/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/2143/0/.cp/
constituent[41]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/Eclipse/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/431/0/.cp/
constituent[42]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/Eclipse/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/26/0/.cp/
---------------------------------------------------
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/util/concurrent/internal/InternalFutureFailureAccess
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1013)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:524)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:427)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:421)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:420)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClassFromSelf(ClassRealm.java:425)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1013)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:524)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:427)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:421)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:420)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClassFromSelf(ClassRealm.java:425)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1013)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:524)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:427)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:421)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:420)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClassFromSelf(ClassRealm.java:425)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.<init>(LocalCache.java:3476)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.<init>(LocalCache.java:3480)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2138)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2049)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3966)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3989)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4950)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.getUnchecked(LocalCache.java:4956)
    at com.google.inject.internal.Annotations$AnnotationChecker.hasAnnotations(Annotations.java:274)
    at com.google.inject.internal.Annotations.isBindingAnnotation(Annotations.java:340)
    at com.google.inject.Key.ensureIsBindingAnnotation(Key.java:349)
    at com.google.inject.Key.strategyFor(Key.java:336)
    at com.google.inject.Key.get(Key.java:219)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.ParameterKeys.<clinit>(ParameterKeys.java:28)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.DependencyAnalyzer.<init>(DependencyAnalyzer.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.ElementAnalyzer.<init>(ElementAnalyzer.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule.configure(WireModule.java:74)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:344)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:103)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:137)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:103)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:87)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:69)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:59)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.addPlexusInjector(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:481)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.<init>(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:206)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.container(MavenCli.java:651)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:196)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.util.concurrent.internal.InternalFutureFailureAccess
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
    ... 74 more
```

What did I miss?

Comment: I don’t know what your issue is, but my advice is to first ensure you can build the project from the command line using`mvn`.  If that works then you know that your issue has something to do with your Eclipse integration.  I also advise adopting the Maven standard directory structure.

Comment: Right, M2Eclipse is buggy, please try to use Maven on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

I coundn't find the root cause. I re-installed eclipse and maven and now it is working, so nothing wrong with the configuration but the tools.